# B-Spline for computing image warps

Tags: interpolation

I have 2 images A and B, and a set of point correspondences S which indicate the position of the same point in the 2 images. The goal is to fit a grid on the image A and warp the grid such that the points get close to the points in image B.

This warping should be modeled by something called bicubic B-spline interpolation, which is implemented in this Matlab toolbox: http://www.brnt.eu/downloads.php#bbs

I am somewhat familiar with 1D B-Splines. What is the mathematical process of modelling the warp using B-Splines?